# How can I improve the typography of this Star Wars Day poster?

Tags: typography, critique, posters

I designed the following poster for social media stories:

[image]

I like the concept; it is not the problem. The **O** is the part of our logo.

I feel that something is wrong with the font size, weight, or spacing, but I am not sure and I cannot identify it. What is it?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have the problem that I have no idea what “social media stories” are, but that may be just me.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft it's just a way of sharing photos/stuff on Facebook, Instagram, WhatsApp etc. That is, I will share it online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doubting about a page/poster layout, there are some visual exercises that can help like:

### See it smaller

More than layout problems I see (or perceive) color problems, too many color variables in a very simple design, actually you are using the three color variables: ink, bright and saturation.

[image]

### See it upside down

While vertical alignments work correctly, horizontal alignments fail when combining elements

- See the number four horizontal stroke, end cap and the *the* baseline.
- See the image end and the top *th* from *the*

[image]

Those are minor details, but personally I think... as you said

> I like the concept; it's not the problem

If you are 100% sure about it, why you don't show it well?

[image]

In your original design I had problems with reading, I've asked myself why the *e* has a different color... I did not distinguish the *4th*. That's why I put a point below in the redesign. Lowering the color contrast of *MAY*, which has already a weight contrast, makes the 4th. stronger, and, in my opinion, the legibility improves.

Making the *e*, *may* and *be with* the same gray it's applying the Gestalt principle of similarity, in this case by color. The *e* stops being a single object, visually becomes part of a group.

It would be good to get some visual information from the [70's Typography Layout](https://www.google.es/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1541&bih=1136&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=8FTNXNTlN6Kp1fAP5bOvqAc&q=70%27s%20typography%20layout%20design&oq=70%27s%20typography%20layout%20design&gs_l=img.3...1708.6926..7364...2.0..0.65.961.16......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i30.gmOqHa7bQiI) when the use of phototypesetting in design allows to make many typographical size combinations, before the digital editing.

Comment: I liked your concept on increasing the length of Light longer. And I also tried the approach of writing BE WITH just next to 4, as you did. But don't you think now eyes tend to read it as MAY the BE WITH YOU. And 4th remains a separate thing now?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Ok, still I need to ask, what do you think about the MAY the BE WITH YOU? Isn't it read first? Earlier in my design, the flow was MAY THE 4TH and then BE WITH YOU. Please explain if possible :)

Comment: What makes you think in your original design this is the reading order? I personally didn't understand the 4, the th, the e is noise and the low color contrast between grays makes it worst.

Comment: Let me insist with the visual information I recommended at the answer.

Comment: That was a creative thing, using th and e so it both supports 4th and the and eventually lessened one word. Otherwise there was no creativity. Still you think e is the noise? Or you are particularly talking about the original design, and they way you improved it, the noise is removed?

Comment: Last update.......

Comment: Got it :D One last question: Why did you make WITH a little larger than BE? To make the vertical distances between **MAY and e** and  **e and WITH**? And the use of DOT to highlight the 4th?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93253/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-and-danielillo).

Comment: @VikasKumar For one on one help, please join us in [The Looking Glass](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36555/the-looking-glass)